# hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto does not link sequence to id column

Tags: sql, hibernate, h2

### Question

*Why I get `NULL not allowed for column "ID"` exception when I execute `INSERT INTO PUBLIC.MY_ENTITY (name) VALUES ('test name');`?*

### Setup

I'm using Spring Boot and Hibernate. Spring Boot is launched with properties:

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

I have entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_ENTITY")
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "MY_ENTITY_SEQ", name = "MyEntitySeq")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MyEntitySeq")
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    // getters & setters
    // ...
}
```

Table has been generated on application start.

I can prove that sequence has been created with the next query:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SEQUENCES WHERE SEQUENCE_NAME = 'MY_ENTITY_SEQ'
```

### P.S.

For some reason Hibernate does not link sequence to id auto generation. I can solve the problem with the query below. *But how make Hibernate generate the query below?*

```
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.MY_ENTITY ALTER COLUMN ID BIGINT DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR PUBLIC.MY_ENTITY_SEQ) NOT NULL NULL_TO_DEFAULT SEQUENCE PUBLIC.MY_ENTITY_SEQ;
INSERT INTO PUBLIC.MY_ENTITY (name) VALUES ('test name');
```

Comment: Help me please, why it does not work?!

Comment: Hi, did you find the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

- Give the @SequenceGenerator an allocationSize: `@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "MY_ENTITY_SEQ", name = "MyEntitySeq", allocationSize=1)`
- Check the dialect you are using
- Set "hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" to "true"

Comment: Issue still present. Added `allocationSize=1`, set `hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true` at *application.properties*, dialect `spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect`